# Any suggestions about how to refresh a js file in django, I changed the URL but its still loading the privious one

Tags: python, json, django

I'm getting this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/move/move_type_rapport 404 (Not Found)
```

But as you can see below, the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/move/move_type_rapport`.

```
const getChartData =() => {
    console.log("fetching");
    fetch("/move/move/move_type_rapport")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((results) => {
            console.log("results", results);
            const type_data = results.move_type_data; 
            const [labels, data] = [
                Object.keys(type_data),
                Object.values(type_data),
            ];

            renderChat(data, labels); 
        });
};

document.onload = getChartData();
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the relevant lines from `urls.py`?

Comment: Hello thanks hedgie

Comment: `#urls.py 
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='move'),
    path('ajouter-move', views.ajouter_move, name='ajouter-move'),
    path('search-move', csrf_exempt(views.search_move), name='search_move'),
    path('move/move/move_type_rapport', views.move_type_rapport, name="move_type_rapport"), 
    path('stat', views.stats_view , name="stat"),         
] `

Comment: Thanks hedgie i resolved by just removing move in the path everywhere